# How to CI/CD deploy static Dockerized React build files to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-integration, devops, aws-codepipeline

I currently have a React application that I have a AWS CodePipeline set up for that does the following.

1. Detect changes in GitHub repository
2. Build the "build" files (with CodeBuild) using buildspec.yaml file
3. Push "build" files to S3 bucket

The S3 bucket is configured to serve the static files to my domain.

This setup is great because it's cheap, I don't need to have an EC2 server always up and running serving these static files, which is completely unnecessary.

Recently however I've Dockerized this application, which is fantastic for me when I'm working on it from different machines.

However now that it's Dockerized it seems like it would be a better idea to have a docker container build the "build" files and push them to the S3 bucket, to ensure that the files being built on my machine are identical to the ones being pushed to the S3 Bucket.

Ideally I would like to have this all be automated when I push to the repo like it currently is.

I've seen a lot of tutorials about how to automate the creation of docker images getting pushed to AWS ECR and then using ECS (Fargate) to run the container. However to me this is just the same thing as running my app on an EC2 server... why do I want to do all this and then have a container continuously running on a server? Now it would just be a ECS server...

So what I am asking is, how can I create an automated CI/CD pipeline that builds the static files using a docker container, and then pushes them to S3, as I currently have it?

Here is current CodeBuild buildspec.yaml file for reference

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12

    commands:
      # install yarn
      - npm install yarn
      # install dependencies
      - yarn
      # so that build commands work
      - yarn add eslint-config-react-app

  build:
    commands:
      # run build script
      - yarn build

artifacts:
  # include all files required to run application
  # we include only the static build files
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'build'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. It is possible to do this without modifying the Source or Deploy sections of the CodePipeline. You do not need EC2,ECR, ECS or Fargate.

You will modify the CodeBuild section of the pipeline to use a buildspec.yml file like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 19

    commands:
      # log in to docker account to prevent rate limiting
      - docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
      # build the Docker image for the application
      - docker build -t my-react-app:latest -f Dockerfile.prod .

  build:
    commands:
      # run container from built image (builds production files)
      - docker run my-react-app:latest
      # set container id to variable
      - CONTAINER=$(docker ps -alq)
      # copy build files from container to host
      - docker cp $CONTAINER:/app/build/ $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/build

artifacts:
  # include all files required to run application
  # we include only the static build files
  files:
    - "**/*"
  base-directory: "build"
```

There are some additional details, I've written a blog post about it here:
https://ncoughlin.com/posts/aws-codepipeline-dockerized-react-s3/